# Display value of variable in view source

Tags: javascript

[image: a busy cat]
![two muppets][1]

I have added the below snippet where arrayProducts is variable in javascript.
Is there any way to display the value in view source for example:-
dynx_itemid : ["A","B"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is not - that's the source.

You can use `console.log(arrayProducts)` to inspect the value in your console.

Usually, pressing F12 in your browser pops up the Developer Tools and the console is somewhere there.